# Remove content of <p>-tags from string

Tags: javascript, regex

My apologies if the question has been asked before, but so far my stackoverflow search didn't bring me quite the answer i needed.
At undetermined intervals my JavaScript is receiving a string containing HTML.

An simplistic example:

```
<p class='commentator'>Person A</p> Comment of Person A <br/> <p class='commentator'> Person B </p> Comment of person B
```

When some conditions are met then all the `<p>` tags and their content should be removed from the string. I know how to remove the `<p>` tags using the following code:

```
stringComments= stringComments.replace(/<\/?p[^>]*>/g, "");
```

How can i modify that regex to include the content of the `<p>` tags? `(regex= .*?)`

*My expected output* should be as follows:

```
Comment of Person A <br/> Comment of person B
```

**Note:** those referring to jQuery's `remove()`. That won't work, first of because its not part of DOM yet & secondly the changes must me limited to this string.

Comment: Nice, [parsing HTML with regexes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) :D

Comment: Are you happy to use jQuery?

Comment: You can use jQuery. It doesn't have to be part of the dom. Just do something like `var e = $(mystringofhtml)`.

Comment: Given your "simplistic example", what *exactly* do you expect the output to be?

Comment: @MattBurland Added the needed output based on the example. Using `$(mystringofhtml)` can i target classes or is the string interpreted as a string (non html)

Comment: @Cerbrus: I'm not aiming at parsing, Just doing a replace (no more, no less). That should be possible with Regex i believe (as it is just an string?)

Comment: @N55PEC: Yes, you can target class. In fact, that's probably a better approach in case somebody changes those `<p>` tags to `<div>`, `<span>` or something else later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use jQuery - don't try to parse HTML with regex, it'll give you no end of trouble. There are lots of ways to do it, but here's one way:

```
var s = "<p class='commentator'>Person A</p> Comment of Person A <br/> <p class='commentator'> Person B </p> Comment of person B";

var elem = $("<div>" + s + "</div>");
var p = elem.find("p");
p.remove();
console.log(elem[0].innerHTML);
```

Logs:

```
Comment of Person A <br>  Comment of person B
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a565cowm/

You don't need to add something to the DOM for jQuery to work on it. jQuery can work with disconnected fragments of HTML.

To be safer, you might even want to use a selector to target the class rather than the `<p>` tag. That way, if it changes to some other tag, or `<p>` tags get added to the content you do want, you won't accidentally end up removing the wrong part.

```
var p = elem.find(".commentator");
```

Edit: For completeness, it should be noted that this isn't a trick limited to jQuery. You can do the same thing in vanilla JS (browser incompatibilities not withstanding):

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = s;
var p = div.getElementsByTagName("p");   // or getElementsByClassName if you prefer
while(p.length > 0) {
    div.removeChild(p[0]);
}
console.log(div.innerHTML);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a565cowm/1/

Comment: Perhaps a very stupid question but: are the `<div>` needed to use the `find()`?

Comment: @N55PEC: `find` looks for children. I'm giving everything a parent. You don't absolutely need to do it that way, but I found it easier for a quick and dirty, coffee hasn't kicked in yet fix.

Comment: Without adding a fake parent, it's kind of tricky because you have the `Comment of Person A` part that doesn't belong to a tag.

Comment: I must say this is quite the discovery for me. knowing that i can use jquery like that.... :)